# Почему параграф уезжает влево если задавать ему максимальную ширину

Tags: css

Мне нужно чтобы данный параграф был по центру и с максимальной шириной, но если задать ему её то он уезжает влево, как это исправить?

```
.about_partners_subtitle{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Futura PT';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 106.7%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 678px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое нужно?

```css
.about_partners_subtitle{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Futura PT';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 106.7%;
    text-align: center;
    /*color: #FFFFFF;*/
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<p class='about_partners_subtitle'>Мне нужно чтобы данный параграф был по центру и с максимальной шириной, но если задать ему её то он уезжает влево, как это исправить?
```